# Why does Stim/PyMatching evaluate the threshold error rate differently for even and odd distances?

Tags: stim, surface-code, toric-code, error-correction

For the toric code, the threshold error rate value for no measurement errors should be around $p_{th}\approx 0.109$. If simulated with even distances, one finds that this is true. However, when I simulate it using odd distances, I find $p_{th}\approx 0.095$: slightly lower. I find this strange considering odd distances are the more practical variant in experiment, and more deterministic than even distances since it always corrects below a certain integer number of errors $\lfloor\frac{d-1}{2}\rfloor$. I wonder why the code gives 2 different outcomes depending on the parity of the code distance. (I used the code from the documentation and simply altered the code distance, so I am fairly sure it's not a coding mistake.)

Logical VS physical error rate for the toric code, for odd and even distances. For some reason, different behaviour is found, regardless of using PyMatching or other decoding programs.
[image]

And here is a higher code distance plot window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Stim and pymatching don't have methods to compute the threshold. How are you actually evaluating it? If you run your method again, how much did the returned threshold change? More or less than this difference? And how many code distances did you try?

Comment: My bad! I am using stim/pymatching as tools to clear up the code, it's not actually those packages that calculate the threshold for me. What I do is simulate the logical error rate through repeated independent runs, as a function of the physical error rate. Then I zoom in around $p\approx 0.1$ and gauge from the image what the crossover is. For 100.000 runs or so, the curves are usually the same and give the same prediction for $p_{th}$. I try this for code distance 3,5,7,9,11 and for d = 4, 8, 12. Even when I write the decoder myself and not use stim or pymatching I get the same behaviour.

Comment: @CraigGidney I included an image in the main text to showcase what I mean. For more runs, these images do not change substantially, and they seem to settle on $p_{th}<0.101$ for odd distances.

Comment: if you do 9,11,13 vs 10,12,14 does the difference get smaller?

Comment: @CraigGidney I added plots of those $d$s in the main text. Indeed it seems that the value increases, not to 0.109, but to around 0.105. I understand that 0.109 might only be reached in the high $d$ limit, but I know people who reported they got it exactly right with their simulations. I manually checked 100s of my simulations, meaning I randomly generated an error pattern, found the inferred error configuration both through a decoder and by hand, and checked if it would affect the logicals. And the code is always right in judging whether a decoder was succesful. So IDK what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't think anything is going wrong I think you're just seeing finite size effects as the amount of boundary-to-bulk decreases go to even bigger code distances. More philosophically, beware that there's very little use in obsessing over +-10% changes in the threshold since there's many other places you get +-10% uncertainties. For example, approximating errors as 100% digitized; using one decoder implementation instead of another; picking the relative weighting of the various errors; ignoring leakage as an error mechanism; etc.

Comment: I see. That's reassuring to hear that perhaps I have been looking too much into the details. Thank you very much for guiding me through this today, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: I always chuckle when I see thresholds listed to 3 sig figs. I've even seen 4. I never trust anything past the first sig fig, and barely that one, due to variations in implementation.